# How to test a class change on a React component based on an event

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a React application and I want to test certain functionality, however, I'm not sure how I should test it.

First of all I'm using `React` and `ReactDOM` version `15.4.2`

I have a component which represents an input button.

```
class InnovanaInputBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = this.initializeState();

        // Bind all the event handlers.
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    initializeState() {
        return {
            hasValue: false
        }
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this.setState(
            {
                hasValue: event.target.value !== ""
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"innovana-input-box" + 
                            (typeof(this.props.className) !== typeof(undefined) &&
                            this.props.className !== "" ? " " + this.props.className: "") +
                            (this.state.hasValue ? " value" : "")}>

                <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
                <label>{this.props.label}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

InnovanaInputBox.PropTypes = {
    label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default InnovanaInputBox;
```

So, when I do enter a value in the input box inside the component, the state `hasValue` does change to `true` if the input box does contain a value.

In the render method, an additional class named `value` it set on the container component.

Now, how can I test this specific behaviour?

I have Karma and Mocha setup and I'm using the `react-addons-test-utils` version `15.4.2`.

I do already have some basic tests to see if the component renders, but testing this seems a bit difficult.

I'm trying to play with `Simulate` and `findReferedDOMComponentWithClass` but I don't get it.

Any advice on how this can be tested?

Kind regads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you aren't specifying a ref on the class, so another way to get the element to test if an element has a class is to go about it like this.

```
const input = document.getElementsByClassName('innovana-input-box')[0];
input.classList.contains('value'); // true
```

Now if there is more than one you may want to either specify an id on the element and use `document.getElementById()` instead. or add a `ref` to the input and use that

[More about refs here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

EDIT:

if you want to test the state value on the component you can do something like this

```
const inputBox = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<InnovanaInputBox />);
const input = React.findDOMNode(inputBox).querySelector('input');
input.value = 'some updated value';
TestUtils.Simulate.change(input);

inputBox.state.hasValue // true
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is not about checking if it has a class, it's more about simulating a change on the input field in the component. The change should then trigger a state change, which should update the class, this is what I want to test. Also, in my question I'm referencing the React Test Utils while the code above is plain JavaScript, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Complexity I dont think Im following you here... if you were going to test that your state updated and the class is applied to the input element.. lets break that into two assertions. so first you want to test that the state changed and second you want to test that the element has a class applied to it. what I gave in my answer is a way to test that the class was applied to the input element. you dont need to use test utils to check if a class was applied. that being said. when you use test utils and render into document. you have a return value. let me update my answer